# How to hide/asterisk a part of the code in R?

Tags: r

I have put in a password inside my code in Rstudio and I just want to somehow make it unclear so when I show my code to someone they don't see the password. Any suggestions for how to do this?
Thanks much

Comment: Are you showing someone inside of the RStudio editor? I don't think you can hide your password like that in the editor, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @AlexA. I have put in a password inside my code in the editor, so if I want to show the code to someone, they will see the password. How can I gloom that password in the editor?

Comment: related: http://www.magesblog.com/2014/07/simple-user-interface-in-r-to-get-login.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should make a new R script (let's call it login_credentials.R) and store your password there

```
username <- "username_here"
password <- "password_here"
```

Once you save that, you can then load that script using source()

This will load the username and password variables.

```
source(login_credentials.R)
> username
[1] "username_here"
> password
[1] "password_here"    

login_function(username,password)
```

Comment: Nice, wouldn't have thought to do it this way. As long as you set the permissions appropriately on `login_credentials.R` so that someone couldn't just open _that_ file to get your info, I think this would be a good way to go.

Comment: @Ken Yeoh  There is just one minor issue here, after R runs source(login_credentials.R), you will see the values for username and password in the Environment panel. How should I deal with this?

Comment: @Mohaa: That's a good point. You might want to consider MrFlick's approach.

Comment: @AlexA. I combined both approaches :) Thanks

Comment: @Mohammad maybe you could add `rm(password)`  to your code after having used the password. Then it won't be around for long :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can obscure your password in the source file.

You can run something like

```
dput(charToRaw("Password"))
# as.raw(c(0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64))
```

to get numeric dump of your password. Then you can include in your script

```
pwd <- as.raw(c(0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64))
login("username", rawToChar(pwd))
```

That will at least make it less-human-readable and there won't be a variable in the environment browser with the text value (at least I think, i'm not sure how RStudio displays raw data).

Comment: I'd be very wary of implementing this as a solution. Someone can very easily call `rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64)))` themselves and see your password in full display

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `.Renviron` file in either your home directory or your project directory, where you store info like this in an environmental variable for use in your R scripts.

If this is the content of `~/.Renviron` or `/path/to/my/project/.Renviron`:

```
YO=secretsecret
```

Then you can retrieve `secretsecret` via `Sys.getenv("YO")`. I wrote up how to do this for API authentication [here](http://stat545-ubc.github.io/bit003_api-key-env-var.html).

**Note:** It can be very important to make sure your `.Renviron` file ends with a line break! Also, you'll need to restart R or Rstudio before this takes effect. Read up on [R startup](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) for more general info.

Answer (score 2):

getPass package would be helpful in your case. This package has a function getPass() which is similar to readline(), the only differnce is that user's text is not printed as it is typed.

For example, consider that the following command creates connection to a database where you normally type the username and password.

> Connection <- dbConnect(driver, connection_parameters, **UserName**, **Password**)

Try replacing the password with getPass() function:

> library(getPass)
> Connection <- dbConnect(driver, connection_parameters, **UserName**, **getPass()**)

So whenever you run this line of code, you would see a popup window asking you to enter ur password. The password would not displayed as you type, but it would be masked as dots (or asterisk).
[Password PopUp window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AikSF.png)

Though this requires you to enter the password every time you run, it at least gives you the ability to mask passwords.

Arguments for the function would be:

> getPass(msg = "PASSWORD: ", noblank = FALSE, forcemask = FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more secure solution would be to store a hash of your password. This can be achieved with the `digest` function:

```
> digest::digest("password")
[1] "380796939c86c55d6aa8ea8c941f7652"
```

This implements the MD5 hash which is a one way cryptographic function and the original password can't be retrieved from this hash, i.e. there is no inverse function.

You will then need to modify the part of your code where you enter the password, hashing the entered password:

```
# Username and password part of code
username <- "username_here"
password_hash <- "380796939c86c55d6aa8ea8c941f7652"

...

# Password testing part of code
if (digest::digest(user_password_input) == password_hash){
   "password_correct"
}else{
   "password_incorrect"}
```

where `user_password_input` is a variable containing the entered password. The hashed password is secure because even if someone has your hashed password, they can't use it to get past the password verification. If they do enter the hash of you password it will be re-hashed and different to the `password_hash` variable.

Using hashes is good practice as your actual passwords are never stored in the code and the hashes by themselves are no use.

Comment: I don't think OP is testing the password, I think OP probably needs to use the password (maybe to pass to an SFTP call).

Comment: I don't really understand your comment but to reiterate my point, storing the password as a hash effectively hides the true password as the hash can't be used in any way get past authentification

Comment: The password testing part of my answer was to demonstrate how you could use the hashed password if you chose to use this suggestion.

Comment: I think the OP *needs* to use the password for authentication (passing it on to log in to something), so as you say, storing it as a hash makes that impossible.